# How to set a parent from one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, insert

I have tables as

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
id varchar(10),
parent_id varchar(10),
Text text,
FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE article_map
(
id varchar(10),
unified_id int(11),
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(id,unified_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

For each `unified_id`, there are several `id`s. The aim is to save all `id`s in the table `article` to avoid being added again, but set one of them as the parent, and the reset as children. In this case, the content (`Text`) is set to `NULL` for all children, and any request to a child redirects to the parent.

How can I `INSERT` from table `article_map` to table `articles` to set one parent and the reset children of the assigned parent for each `unified_id`? There is no preference for choosing the parent.

Comment: Please change `id` (in article_map) to `article_id`.  The name `id` has baggage that you violated.  The _name_ `id` is usually an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Since `article_map` is a many:many table, perhaps you also want `INDEX(unified_id, article_id)` to facilitate linking the opposite direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` an correlated subqueries.

In the subquery select the minimum `id` for the row's `unified_id`.

If the row's `id` is equal to this minimum, parent is null, making the article a parent. If it isn't equal to the minimum it's a child of the article with the minimum `id`. Set the minimum `id` as parent then.

```
INSERT INTO articles
            (id,
             parent_id)
            SELECT amo.id id,
                   CASE
                     WHEN amo.id = (SELECT min(ami.id)
                                           FROM article_map ami
                                           WHERE ami.unified_id = amo.unified_id)
                       THEN null
                     ELSE
                       (SELECT min(ami.id)
                               FROM article_map ami
                               WHERE ami.unified_id = amo.unified_id)
                   END parent
                   FROM article_map amo;
```

Or you can use a union. First select all parents using the minimum and a `GROUP BY unified_id`. Unify that with an `INNER JOIN` of `article_map` an the parents.

```
INSERT INTO articles
       SELECT min(am.id) id,
              null
              FROM article_map am
              GROUP BY am.unified_id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT amo.id id,
              p.id parent
              FROM article_map amo
                   INNER JOIN (SELECT min(ami.id) id,
                                      ami.unified_id
                                      FROM article_map ami
                                      GROUP BY ami.unified_id) p
                              ON p.unified_id = amo.unified_id
                                 AND p.id <> amo.id;
```

(Minimum and maximum (and possibly others) are interchangeable here of course.)